# Having issues with pulling data to a listbox, MySQL to VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=Password;database=giordydatabase")
        conn.Open()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM student ORDER BY firstName;")
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "student")
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("student")
        For Each row As DataTable In dataTable.Rows
            Dim newStudent As New Student
            newStudent.strFirstName = row.Item("firstName")
            newStudent.strLastName = row.Item("lastName")
            Dim mainStudentList As Object = Nothing
            mainStudentList.add(newStudent)
            lstStudents.item.add(newStudent.nameConcat)(newStudent.strFirstName, strLastName)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have an issue as I would like to connect my database to the listbox, also would like it to pull data only the first name and last name data and combine the two to create a name for a list for students to select themselves. But the code above isn't allowing me to do this.

Note the list box is only there for user selection and once they select themselves the they can use the application under the name they selected.

Comment: What is the question or issue?

Comment: @Plutonix The issue is that when I run the code above, firstly it's bugged with many errors and also I can't figure a way to connect the listbox to the MySQL database. Note that vb.net to mysql is new to me.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the fact that you are setting your main students list to type object and as nothing...

Try to move this line

> Dim mainStudentList As Object = Nothing

out of where it is nested and move it so that it is the FIRST line in your code block...

Also instead of what you got currently in that line, change it to...

> Dim mainStudentList As Generic.List(Of Student)

Finally change this line...

> lstStudents.item.add(newStudent.nameConcat)(newStudent.strFirstName, strLastName)

to ...

> lstStudents.item.add(Trim(newStudent.strFirstName) & " " & Trim(newStudent.strLastName))

Try that and see what happens, Good luck.